# Where is "views" directory in WordPress installation?

Tags: wordpress

This might be a stupid question but I am not able to locate the "views" directory inside my WordPress install.

I need to do some work in `media-views.js`, which is located in `wp/includes/js` directory. At line 2291, it has the entry:

```
media.view.AttachmentFilters = require( './views/attachment-filters.js');
```

I tried

```
sudo find ~/ -type f -name 'attachment-filters.js'
sudo find / -type f -name 'attachment-filters.js'
```

(staying at WordPress installation root) but did not find the file.

When I tried to search **views** directory with

```
sudo find . -type d -name "views"`
```

it only fetched `./wp-content/plugins/akismet/views`!

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/js/media/views

Comment: Sorry for bothering you for one more time! I am on 4.8.1 and the folder structure is different. For me it is like `wp-includes/js/mediaelement`. There is no `wp-includes/js/media/views/` directory. Where is the file? I want to add a taxonomy filter dorpdown in media library for which I found https://gist.github.com/danielbachhuber/0e4ff7ad82ffc15ceacf for it but without the folder present I don't understand where to put it! Also if the folder is not present how `media.view.AttachmentFilters = require( './views/attachment-filters.js' );` this is being accessed? And yes, thank you for edits!

Answer (score 0):

**General answer**

As I understood, the `wp-includes/js/media` is only in the source code (in github). Those are js modules that are then concatenated and transformed by their build pipeline.

See this issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28510

> Split javascript files in media into modules: *This will only affect the src/ directory in the develop repository, which will use our build process to concatenate* into the build/ directory, so nothing will change for developers using the build/ directory or the core repo.
>   We'll start this effort with **media**, and end up with a standardized way of doing this going forward.

To better understand how all of this works, I suggest this article https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/01/22/the-case-for-js-modules/, which explains the *WordPress Backbone* more in depth.

---

**As for your specifiy need**

In WordPress, you use themes, plugins, hooks and filters to customize your site. You don't alter the source code directly !

If your need is to define custom attachment filters, you need to use *filters*, they are there precisely for that. Have a look at https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-add-extra-media-type-filters-to-the-wordpress-media-manager--wp-25998 for an example.